# Foreman start script

Tags: background, foreman, descartes

I'm facing an issue with my Foreman script. I've installed it following the installation path from Descartes article in GitHub (https://github.com/obfuscurity/descartes). The scripts functions great but I have two things going on.

1- How can I run it in background mode?

2- After a while the service will fall without any apparent reason.

$ cd /descartes_folder/

$ foreman start

> 13:12:43 web.1  | started with pid 3011
>   13:12:46 web.1  | >> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>   13:12:46 web.1  | >> Maximum connections set to 1024
>   13:12:46 web.1  | >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:5000, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to stop

I tried to send its output to a log file, but the only I got was:

> 19:30:11 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
>   19:30:11 web.1  | exited with code 0

Like if there was a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Any ideas? anything would be really appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just gave up on Foreman. No answer from any of the portals, forums, google groups..even I tried to contact the guy who wrote it directly, still nothing. Finally got another web console for my Graphite metrics (dashboard) and discarded Descartes (the one requiring Foreman).
Thanks anyway!